# Mongodb "Can't canonicalize query" error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

### Objective

Find what is wrong with my MongoDB query

### Background

I have a drinks collection, where I enter data like the following:

```
    db.smoothies.insert({
    name: "Orange Banana",
    ingredients: [], //list of ingredients
    preparation: "Mix everything and have fun!",
    Source: "Super Smoothies, p. 142"
})
```

I am trying to create a search by name functionality, and to achieve it I have created a `$text` index, according to the documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

So I used the following:

```
db.smoothies.createIndex({name: 'text'})
```

Now, when I make a simple `find` query like the following one, it works:

```
db.smoothies.find({ $text: { $search: "Orange" } })
```

But when i try to define case sensitivity, it fails:

```
db.smoothies.find( { $text: { $search: "orange", $caseSensitive: true } } )
```

And I get the following error:

```
error: {
        "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue extra fields in $text",
        "code" : 17287
}
```

### Question

I have taken this example from the documentation, and I can't understand why it fails. Can someone help me figure it out?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this and it worked without error. Which mongo version are you using?

Comment: db version v2.6.12
  git version: d73c92b1c85703828b55c2916a5dd4ad46535f6a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need mongodb version 3.2 at least to use this query

have a look at the 2.6 documentation for text index :

https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/core/index-text/